# Git ssh connection refused with the following format

Tags: macos, git, ssh

Whenever I use the following

```
url = ssh://user@dev.example.com:imageInfo.git
```

in .git/config for a remote repo I get the following error

```
 ssh: connect to host  port 22: Connection refused
 fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

but if use the following

```
ssh user@dev.example.com
```

outside of git I connect without a problem.
 Git also connects to same server with a gitosis user using

```
 url = gitosis@dev.example.com:imageInfo.git
```

in .git/config and it has not problems.

so to sum things up in short my .git/config file looks like this

```
 [remote "production"]
        url = ssh://user@dev.example.com:imageInfo.git
        url = gitosis@dev.example.com:imageInfo.git
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have the format of the SSH URL wrong - you can either use the `scp`-style syntax, like:

```
user@dev.example.com:imageInfo.git
```

... or the true URL form, where you need a `/` after the host rather than a `:`, and an absolute path, which I can only guess at, e.g.:

```
ssh://user@dev.example.com/srv/git/imageInfo.git
```

The documentation for git's URLs [is here](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#URLS), but `kernel.org` is down at the moment, so you may want to look at the cached version [here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aTgm6QVLCfx0J%3awww.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clone.html&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk&client=ubuntu#URLS).

Answer (score 0):

I got this message due to not having **sshd** daemon installed and running. So I did **'sudo apt-get install ssh'** and the issue was solved.