# Why will xcode not allow me to connect to my git server? What does "Server is disabled" mean?

Tags: xcode, git, ssh

I can connect to my server keyless via ssh.  I can clone on this account on my mac from my git server.

Xcode's preferences accepted my git server settings with a URL like this:

```
ssh://git@mediapc/home/git/sk001.git
```

When creating a new xcode project which I want on the server with my git repos, I get a dialog that pops up with the message below.

```
Server is disabled
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7426474/1698426 helped me get the URL correct, though I have tried both the scp style and the true URL style.

I thought the "new project..." dialogs would allow me to select my configured repository, but it does not.